# How to mark a REST service as deprecated in RAML

Tags: raml

We are making an updated to our RAML 0.8 specification and we want to mark a method as deprecated and point to another method in the same API. Is that possible in RAML? I read some articles but it is not clear if it is implemented yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAML 0.8 lacks this concept. RAML 1.0 added the Annotations to the global section to convey such meta data.

P.S.: A sample deprecation annotation

```
deprecated:
  properties:
    replaceWith:
      type: string
      description: |
        Describe the alternative resource/method that can be used as a substitute.
      required: true
    since:
      type: string
      pattern: (0[1-9]|10|11|12)/20[0-9]{2}
      required: true
      description: Describe when the resource/method became deprecated in the format (mm/YYYY)
  allowedTargets: [Resource, Method]
  displayName: Deprecated
  description: |
    A deprecated resource or method is *not* recommended for new work.
    The resource or method will be removed in a future version of the API.

    Deprecation does NOT mean it is not supported anymore in the current version.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I checked that further and it is exactly as you said